# Append to one of two columns, then other column

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code sorts the `.dataCard` elements by the `data-cardNumber` attribute's values and then appends them in the order to `#main`.

How can I append them to the `#left` or `#right`?

How I want it to decide between `#left` or `#right` is to measure the height of both `#left` and `#right` and compare them.

If `#left` is taller / longer then append to `#right`, if `#right` is taller / longer then append to `#left`, and if they are both the same height then append to `#left`.

```
var m = $('#main .dataCard').sort(function(a, b){
    return $(a).data('cardnumber') - $(b).data('cardnumber');
}).appendTo('#main');
```

I would greatly appreciate any and all help in achieving this sorting into one column or the other based on height.

Thanks in Advance!
                                        }

Comment: Can I see this in action with a http://www.jsfiddle.com please?  It would be easier if we knew all of the elements involved and the CSS you're using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/f6SNY/)</kbd>

```
var left = $('#left'), //cache selector
    right = $('#right'), //cache selector
    append_to_div;
if (left.height() < right.height()) { //compare height
    append_to_div = right;
} else {
    var append_to_div = left;
}

var x = $('#main .dataCard').sort(function (a, b) {
    return $(a).data('cardnumber') - $(b).data('cardnumber');
});

append_to_div.html(x); //html will add new list of items where as append will add items top previous elements
```

---

Updated after OP's comment

<kbd>[**Updated fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/f6SNY/3)</kbd>

```
var left = $('#left'),
    right = $('#right'),
    l = [],
    r = [];

var x = $('#main .dataCard').sort(function (a, b) {
    return $(a).data('cardnumber') - $(b).data('cardnumber');
});
for (var i = 0; i < left.children().length; i++) {
    l.push(x[i]);
}
for (var i = left.children().length; i < left.children().length + right.children().length; i++) {
    r.push(x[i]);
}
left.html(l);
right.html(r);
```

---

Shorter and better version of above code

<kbd>[**Updated fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/f6SNY/4)</kbd>

```
var left = $('#left'),
    right = $('#right'),
    arr = [];

var x = $('#main .dataCard').sort(function (a, b) {
    return $(a).data('cardnumber') - $(b).data('cardnumber');
});
arr = $.makeArray(x);
left.html(arr.slice(0, left.children().length));
right.html(arr.slice(left.children().length));
```

Comment: In the JSFiddle, the items are all in one column. They need to be in the different columns according to height of the column.

Comment: Cards to be sorted and then placed in both left or right. According to fiddle it looks like they are all being placed in left. Some should be in left and some should be in right. Or is that because they are all the same height?

Answer (score 1):

While iterating through your `.dataCard`'s you can do something like this to check the height and append the `.dataCard` accordingly.

```
var x = $('#main .dataCard').sort(function (a, b) {
    return $(a).data('cardnumber') - $(b).data('cardnumber');
});

for(var i = 0; i < x.length;i++){
    if($('#left').height() <= $('#right').height()){
        $('#left').append(x[i]);
    }
    else
        $('#right').append(x[i]);  
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/p9q6h/2/

Comment: @gomangomango I should have an update that does what you want now.

Answer (score 0):

just check for the height of `left` and `right` everytime and compare.

```
var toAppend,
    $left = $("#left"),
    $right = $("#right");

$left.height() > $right.height() ? toAppend = $right : toAppend = $left;
```

Use the `toAppend` variable now.